# Shared storage FS (GFS2, GlusterFS, ?) comparison and test

Tags: glusterfs, gfs

**Problem description**: For our application (RHEL 5,6) we use shared storage (EVA) and need to find *OCFS2 replacement* (not supported on RHEL 6) for several FS shared between nodes (2-7). Current tips are *GFS2* and *GlusterFS*.

**Usage**: System receives (SFTP/SCP) and process files size 10-100 MB which process (create, rename in directory, move between directories, read, remove).

**Limitations**: The amount of data processed this way (create, remove) is up to `3 TB/day` (max `60 MB/s`). The filesystem shall be able to handle thousands of such files in a single directory during backlog.

**Reason for GFS2/GlucterFS**: Both are RedHat. Reason for trying GlusterFS comparing to GFS2 is simplicity, GFS2 requires RH cluster installation while GlusterFS not. The question is performance.

It could be really helpful to both get some more recommendations and/or find some comparison (I know they are generally of different types, but anyway).

Thanks
Jan

Comment: # Comparison OCFS2, GFS2, GlusterFS #

## Conditions ##

* 2-node cluster, EVA-4400 storage
* Set of 50MB files pre-prepared  on local disks 

## Results ##

* With single activity (R or W) performance of all shared FS seems to be comparable
* With both R&W GlusterFS R performance degradates rapidly